# Any ASP.NET Opensource project that works on both SQL Server and MS Access DB?

Tags: asp.net

I searched on Google and I can't find any, do you know some ?

Comment: I don't understand, you are looking for a project that connects to both SQL Server and MS Access? A project that would do what?

Comment: I'm look for any sample project (blog, cms, ecommerce) that can work with both. I once encountered a blog but don't remember the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware. Most open source projects however use one specific database engine (which makes sense), or xml (for example dasBlog).

However you can always swap your SQL Server for MS Access in a project if you want. The provider system for membership etc in ASP.NET itself is already a great example of that possibility (though not open source as it comes from Microsoft). For example take a look at this tutorial: [Using Access instead of SQL server for your ASP.NET Application Services](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingAccessInsteadOfSQLServerForYourASPNETApplicationServices.aspx).

Personally I would rather find it strange to see an open source project making use of 2 different, especially MS Access in the first place. People tend to use SQL Server Express or SQLite or SQL CE for something like this.

Comment: Thanks for this link very interesting. As for access it's because there are a lot of ms access applications in my corporate enterprise, users don't want to manipulate sql express so it is usefull to also offer ms access format.